# SQL is declarative, what about LINQ

Tags: linq

I can change SQL at runtime.
Can I do the same with LINQ ? 
Can I have LINQ queries coming from an xml file, which I can edit at runtime ?

Comment: I don't think this is what "declarative" means. Maybe "dynamic" or "ad-hoc"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and yes, via the expression tree creation syntax.